# 2D Array: Program reading eight marks for 40 different students

Tags: java

> This program should reads in eight marks for 40 different students
>   using a 2D array.
>           Column showing the eight marks.Row showing the 40 different students.

```
package pkg2d.array;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Array 
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
  //delcare arrays  
  double[][] marksTable;

  //Declare variables
  double mark;
  int studentNo;
  int moduleNo;

  //Allocate elements
  marksTable = new double[40][8];

  //Create Scanner object
  Scanner fromKeyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

  for(studentNo = 1; studentNo <= 40; studentNo++)
  {
      System.out.print("Enter marks for student no " +studentNo);

      for (moduleNo = 1; moduleNo <= 8; moduleNo++)
      {
          System.out.print("Mark for student "+studentNo+" for module no "+moduleNo+":");
          mark = fromKeyboard.nextDouble();
          marksTable[studentNo][moduleNo] = mark;
      }    
  }
} //end main
} //end class'
```

I cannot seem to have the 40 different students to be at the row side
and 
the eight marks to be at the column side.

What did I not do in this program??

Comment: Indices start at 0 in java and go up to `length-1`.

Answer (score 1):

Since array indexes start at zero, not one, you need to do one of two things:

- Change your loops to go from 0 to 39, inclusive, and from 0 to 7, inclusive, and print loop index plus one, or
- Keep the loops as is, and use `marksTable[studentNo-1][moduleNo-1]` in your indexing.

The first approach is more common:

```
for(int studentNo = 0 ; studentNo < marksTable.length ; studentNo++) {
      System.out.print("Enter marks for student no " +(studentNo+1));
      for (int moduleNo = 0 ; moduleNo < marksTable[studentNo].length ; moduleNo++) {
          System.out.print("Mark for student "+(studentNo+1)+" for module no "+(moduleNo+1+":");
          ...
      }
}
```